# Stripe Webhook error 400 with netlify functions

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, webhooks, netlify-function

I have set up payments with stripe using Netlify function by following this article https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/04/22/automate-order-fulfillment-w/stripe-webhooks-netlify-functions/ and in my Stripe dashboard I get error saying that:
***Webhook Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing***

Now I am not sure if the user gets confirmation email, Sendgrid does not show any activity, however it has not shown any when I was testing this flow previously, and although I received confirmation email. Unfortunately back then I pressed resend by my webhook activity details in Stripe dashboard, and I am not sure if I should be resending those or do they go through. Would anyone be able to tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.handler = async ({ body, headers }) => {
  try {
    const stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
      body,
      headers["stripe-signature"],
      process.env.STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET
    );

    if (stripeEvent.type === "charge.succeeded") {
      const emailTo = stripeEvent.data.object.billing_details.email;

      const msg = {
        to: emailTo,
        from: process.env.FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
        subject: `Thanks!`,
        html: `elox`,
      };
      await sgMail.send(msg);
    }

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ received: true }),
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Stripe webhook failed with ${err}`);

    return {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: `Webhook Error: ${err.message}`,
    };
  }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.
Locally with the stripes-cli everything works fine.
It seems that the lambda didn't hand over the raw body to the `stripes.webhook.constructEvent.`

Therefore my solution was to change the method signature to the following and use the `event.body` object.

```
exports.handler = async(event, context ) => {
    try {
        const stripeEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
            event.body,
            event.headers['stripe-signature'],
            endpointSecret
        );....
```

Comment: This still can't work, as event.body is the same parsed data as always. Seems like Netlify doesn't offer a raw version of the incoming data. (AWS Lambdas do.)

Comment: Did you guys ever figure this one out? I'm running into the same issue.